# Rails: Page specific javascript running on every page if visited in same window

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, browser-cache, turbolinks

I wanted to run javascript for some particular page. To accomplish this I have created meta tag in layout file like this:

```
<%= tag :meta, name: :psj, action: action_name, controller: controller_name %>
```

I have also created a `init.js` file that will be loaded by application manifest file.

```
# init.js
var Page, bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };
Page = (function() {
  function Page() {
    this.action = bind(this.action, this);
    this.controller = bind(this.controller, this);
  }
  Page.prototype.controller = function() {
    return $('meta[name=psj]').attr('controller');
  };
  Page.prototype.action = function() {
    return $('meta[name=psj]').attr('action');
  };
  return Page;
})();
this.page = new Page;
```

Here is my javascript file for specific controller that need to run on specific action:

```
# scans.js
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  if (!(page.controller() === 'scans' && page.action() === 'index')) { return; }

  var ajax_call = function() {
    $.get("/scans.js", { }, function(table) {
      $("#scans").replaceWith(table);
    });
  }

  var interval = 1000 * 60 * 1 ;
  setInterval(ajax_call, interval);
});
```

This works perfect for the `scans#index` page. Now after visiting this page if I click on any link that loads **some other page in same window**, `ajax_call` code runs which should not be the case.

On the contrary if I open that other page in different window it works fine (`ajax_call` don't run). Is it somehow related to browser's cache or turbolinks cache, not sure what is the cause of the problem.

Comment: 1) Use websockets 2) Don't update the DOM if nothing changed 3) A request to `anything.js` should not return HTML, 4) Why not simply write this in a dedicated JS file and load it in the view you need it in?

Comment: The code is already in separate js file, edited for more clarity.

Comment: You don't need any of `init.js` or the conditional in `scans.js` if you're only loading this in the view for `scans#index`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is that you've instrumented Turbolinks but you're not actually listening to the page change events to manipulate the state. I.e., when the page changes, you need to clear your interval. Turbolinks doesn't handle the browser opening a new window and navigating to a URL (e.g. super+click), hence why it works in those instances.

Comment: is it somehow realted to cache, updated the question

Comment: @RajMishra There isn't a way for Turbolinks to capture all of the JS that loaded during a particular `load` callback, so they don't tear it down for you. If you need to do so, as you do here, you need to do it yourself. https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#full-list-of-events

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {    
  let interval = null;
  if ((page.controller() === 'scans' && page.action() === 'index')) {
    let ajax_call = function() {
      $.get("/scans.js", { }, function(table) {
        $("#scans").replaceWith(table);
      });
    }
    let interval = 1000 * 60 * 1 ;
    interval = setInterval(ajax_call, interval);
  }else{
    if(interval){ clearInterval(interval) }
  }
}
```